# amp-bind format value output on event

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to format the output of a number value to make it more readable on a `amp-bind` however, I cannot see how I can implement a regex on the `event.output` value?

Currently, I have the following;

```
                <label class="form-title">
                    <span>How much do you need?</span>
                    <span [text]="[amount]">
                        £1500000
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input type="range"
                       name="amountSlider"
                       min="10000"
                       step="10000"
                       value="1500000"
                       max="3000000"
                       on="change: AMP.setState({ amount: '£' + event.value.replace('/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g', ',')})">
```

However, this results in the error;

```
%s %s amp-bind: Expression eval failed. [object String].replace is not a supported function.​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

The function 'replace' is not a white-listed function:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#white-listed-functions

For your purpose, maybe something along the line:

> "12345678.1".split(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/).join(",")
>
> "12,345,678.1"

since 'split' is white-listed. WARNING: I did not test it out on an AMP page!

Comment: I couldn’t find a white listed functions page. Thanks for that. I’ll give it a go.